# GAE Mail Send Quota = 100/day?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, quota, google-app-engine-php

I have my own domain with G-Suite Business and application in GAE that sending emails to our clients. But limit 100 sendings per day is too low.

How to increase mail send quota above 100/day? That's possible?

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: You can ask Google Support to increase the limit, or use a third party service as recommended in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mail/#quotas_and_limits)

Answer (score 1):

The build in GAE mail is not really intended for production use, on top of the 100 mail limit there is also a limit on how many unique email addresses can be sent to in 1 day if im not mistaken.

For production I would recommend SendGrid, documentation can be found here : https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mail/sendgrid

Good service with a lot of needed mail features, like custom domain etc.

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud Platform support no longer provides quota increases for the Mail API.

Besides that, Richard's reply is correct so you can use Sendgrid or other available mail providers mentioned in the documentation. Additionally, as you mentioned GSuite, you may consider using [Sockets API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/sockets/) with your GSuite accounts (subject to GSuite quota).